# Where is the location of .babelrc file?

Tags: babeljs

I have installed Babel and found out that in order to compile JSX, .babelrc file needs to be changed? Where is the file located? I was looking in the babel-preset, babel, babel-jsx folders and so on, but could not find it? Should it be created manually?

Answer (score 22):

.babelrc is never auto created.  You must go to the root directory of your project. Create a file - touch .babelrc, open the file and enter the babel settings here, then save.  If you are following https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6, Setting up Babel 6 and installed all the plugins and presets as stated, this may help.

```js
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "env",
    "react",
    "stage-2"
  ]
},

{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
    "check-es2015-constants",
    "transform-es2015-block-scoping"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 17):

The `.babelrc` file is your local configuration for your code in your project. Generally you would put it in the root of your application repo. It will affect all files that Babel processes that are in the same directory or in sibling directories of the `.babelrc`.

Comment: @Kalanamith I've always created it manually, or copied it from project to project. I don't know of a tool that would create it for you.

Comment: I put it in the root folder and the configuration is not working. Did you know any common issues related to it?

Comment: @KeepMove Could be the the difference between Babel 6 and 7 (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#6x-vs-7x-babelrc-loading ? May be worth making it a `babel.config.js` instead.

Comment: @loganfsmyth It's fixed. It was because I copied the file from vscode to windows file explorer that made the file someway like corrupted and not read as babel config file.

Answer (score 11):

.babelrc  could potentially exist in several places in the node tree.

The project root folder would see to be most likely. The babel config could also be specified within package.json under "babel:" {...}

Lookup behavior

Babel will look for a .babelrc in the current directory of the file being transpiled. If one does not exist, it will travel up the directory tree until it finds either a .babelrc, or a package.json with a "babel": {} hash within.

Use "babelrc": false to stop lookup behavior.

See https://github.com/insin/babel-plugin-react-html-attrs/blob/master/README.md  and Look Up behavior-

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The fact it searches up the directory tree is immensely useful. Particularly if you combine that with `"extends": "../../../path/to/root/.babelrc"`.

Answer (score 2):

.babelrc file is a hidden file in Mac and Linux. In Windows you still will be able to see it. The only way to see in Mac and Linux is using command line.